# Looping Through an Array with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, list, loops

I have a question about creating Custom Lists with User Friendly touch.

I have the following example:

```
var unitA = [];
unitA[0] = "Unit A One";
unitA[1] = "Unit A Two";
unitA[2] = "Unit A Three";

var unitB = [];
unitB[0] = "Unit B One";
unitB[1] = "Unit B Two";
unitB[2] = "Unit B Three";

var level = [];
level[0] = "Level 1";
level[1] = "Level 2";
level[2] = "Level 3";

var skill = [];
skill[0] = "This has Skill 1";
skill[1] = "This has Skill 2";
skill[2] = "This has Skill 3";
skill[3] = "This has Skill 4";

$('<div class="units"></div>').appendTo('body');

var unit = [];
$.each(unitA, function(index, value) {unit.push('<div class="unitA-'+index+' u">'+value+'</div>');});
$.each(unitB, function(index, value) {unit.push('<div class="unitB-'+index+' u">'+value+'</div>');});
$(".units").html(unit.join(""));
```

The code above would loop through unitA and unitB and output data to HTML body in the DIV.

```
Unit A One
Unit A Two
Unit A Three
Unit B One
Unit B Two
Unit B Three
```

After I do this:

```
$(".unitA-0").append(
                '<ul>'+level[0]+'<li>'+skill[0]+'</li><li>'+skill[1]+'</li><li>'+skill[2]+'</li><li>'+skill[3]+'</li></ul>',
                '<ul>'+level[1]+'<li>'+skill[0]+'</li><li>'+skill[1]+'</li><li>'+skill[2]+'</li><li>'+skill[3]+'</li></ul>'
                );

$(".unitA-1").append(
                '<ul>'+level[0]+'<li>'+skill[0]+'</li><li>'+skill[1]+'</li></ul>',
                '<ul>'+level[1]+'<li>'+skill[1]+'</li></ul>',
                '<ul>'+level[2]+'<li>'+skill[0]+'</li><li>'+skill[1]+'</li><li>'+skill[2]+'</li><li>'+skill[3]+'</li></ul>'
                );
```

This would output data as:

```
Unit A One
> Level 1 > Skill 1 / Skill 2 / Skill 3 / Skill 4
> Level 2 > Skill 1 / Skill 2 / Skill 3 / Skill 4
Unit A Two
> Level 1 > Skill 1 / Skill 2
> Level 2 > Skill 2
> Level 3 > Skill 1 / Skill 2 / Skill 3 / Skill 4
Unit A Three
Unit B One
Unit B Two
Unit B Three
```

My goal is to create user friendly and maintainable code similar to List / Menu / Navigation style as I might have many of the Units, Levels and Skills.

If anyone can suggest how to create more efficient logic to handle this.

More like:

```
unitA-1+level-1+skill-1+skill-2
unitA-1+level-2+skill-1+skill-4+skill-5
```

Would output:

```
<div class="unitA-1">Unit Name 1
<ul class="level-1">Level Name 1
<li>Skill Name 1</li>
<li>Skill Name 2</li>
</ul>
<ul class="level-2">Level Name 2
<li>Skill Name 1</li>
<li>Skill Name 4</li>
<li>Skill Name 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you may want to first look at how you're storing the data.

With this kind of relational model (Units have Levels which have Skills), you may want to use a JSON-like way of storage. For Example:

```
var units = [
    {
        name   : 'Unit Name 1',
        levels : [
            {
                name   : 'Level Name 1',
                skills : [
                    'Skill Name 1',
                    'Skill Name 2'
                ]
            },
            {
                name   : 'Level Name 2',
                skills : [
                    'Skill Name 1',
                    ...
                ]
            },
            ...
        ]
    },
    {
        name   : 'Unit Name 2',
        levels : [
            ...
        ]
    },
    ... 
];
```

You can loop through these with jQuery like:

```
$(units).each(function (unitIndex, unitValue) {
    // Print <div>unitValue.name</div>
    $(unitValue.levels).each(function (levelIndex, levelValue) {
        // Print header for list (levelValue.name) and <ul>
        $(levelValue.skills).each(function (skillIndex, skillValue) {
            // Print <li>skillValue</li>
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: It worked! I used var $unit = $('<div class="'+unitIndex+'">'+unitValue.name+'</div>'); and at the end $('body').append($unit.append($level.append($skill)));